# LocalSettings breaking on unhandled XAML exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am having some trouble figuring out why, when I try to define [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) to a field so I can access it from multiple methods, it performs a break during a debug run within App.g.i.cs at the following code:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Here is my actual class:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ApplicationDataContainer _localSettings;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    }
}
```

I have tried wrapping it in a try/catch statement, yet that did not catch the exception, so I have no idea what is causing this.

I have also tried directly copying the code from the LocalSettings page linked above, which produces the same problem as my code.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and preferably also where I can find a solution?

Comment: What the exception says? Also, maybe there is a xaml code that produces exception?

Comment: It doesn't give me any exception, at least not one that I can find, it just breaks at the mentioned code (even though there is no breakpoint there), I have tried to catch the exception, but using a try/catch doesn't catch it. The XAML could be causing an exception I guess, but it's a clean/fresh UWP app, and it works just fine without the 1 line `_localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;`

Comment: Have you tried to clean solution, restart VS, start other project and give it a try?

Comment: I finally managed to get an actual exception message, apparently the default VS exception break settings did not cover this one and thus didn't throw it where I could find it. Also, had to move the whole code that defined the LocalSettings to App.xaml.cs instead of the MainPage.xaml.cs. Here is the message: [link](http://hastebin.com/ikimihagoy.pas)

Comment: @Romasz yes, tried all of that, moving the code to App.xaml.xs instead of MainPage.xaml.cs throws a different exception that I managed to catch here: [link](http://hastebin.com/ikimihagoy.pas)

Comment: Can you try [to switch to MS account](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7347a0ce-0db3-4b56-b1c2-95ddbdda88b4/unable-to-access-to-localsettings-or-roamingsettings?forum=winappswithcsharp)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129111/discussion-between-dion-s-jensen-and-romasz).

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955018/applicationdata-current-roamingsettings